# Grails, making sure that map is unique

Tags: grails, mapping

:D
I have this map:

```
[channel:Provider]
```

How do I make sure that the map (and I mean, the pairing of channel + Provider) become unique? Is there a super easy way to do that? Or should I create a custom validator for it.. T__T I think I can add a unique constraint to the table that contains both columns, but I'm a bit new to grails, this GORM thing is preventing me from acting out my thoughts.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem.  Do you want it unique across domain objects that might have this map as a property?  As it is right now, if Foo is your domain object and it has a map property that has `[channel: Provider]`, if you try to add another `channel` property, it'd just override the previous one so uniqueness isn't an issue.  If you want only one Foo to have a `channel` with that `Provider` that is a different situation.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

All maps guarantee that that the pairing of key and value is unique, because you can't have duplicate keys. It seems that either I'm misunderstanding what you want to achieve, or you're misunderstanding how maps work.